# Map doesn't show for D3.js (TopoJSON)

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I'm trying to display my TopoJSON file using D3.js library but my map doesn't show. The zip.topojson file works on mapshaper.org. Could anyone help me to figure out what is wrong?

```
var margin = { top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom
var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right


var svg = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "zips.topojson")
    .await(ready)




// var projection = d3.geoMercator()
//  .translate([width / 2, height / 2]) // center it

var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(130)

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection)




function ready(error, data) {
    console.log(data);

    // every time you pull out topojson
    var zips = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.zips).features
    console.log(zips);

    svg.selectAll(".zip")
        .data(zips)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "zip")
        .attr("d", path)

}
```

My zips.topojson file (I retrieved it using QGIS):

```
{"type":"Topology","objects":{"zips":{"type":"GeometryCollection","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"id":null},"arcs":[[0]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"id":null},"arcs":[[1,2,3]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"id":null},"arcs":[[4]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"id":null},"arcs":[[5,6,7,8]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"id":null},"arcs":[[9,10]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"id":null},"arcs":[[11]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"id":null},"arcs":[[-3,12,13]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"id":null},"arcs":[[14]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"id":null},"arcs":[[-4,-14,15,-6,16]]},{"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"id":null},"arcs":[[[17]],[[-10,18]]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"id":null},"arcs":[[19,-8]]}]}},"arcs":[[[4351,7522],[433,194],[59,-154],[22,-34],[80,17],[31,-21],[80,-212],[130,39],[128,11],[81,-17],[-79,-308],[-139,6],[23,-33],[-66,-109],[-130,-62],[-281,-36],[-63,59],[-29,-27],[-34,29],[-10,69],[90,93],[38,55],[-30,93],[-178,-66],[-92,243],[-14,27],[-50,144]],[[3369,6110],[249,160],[67,-31],[77,98],[46,-48],[25,54],[21,33],[176,-72],[88,114],[103,-60],[96,110],[21,-64],[128,112],[71,-27],[86,-292]],[[4623,6197],[-107,65],[-76,-100],[45,-33],[-74,-130],[-92,61],[-268,48],[-105,-192],[-54,-192],[-23,7]],[[3869,5731],[21,77],[-235,-13],[-222,171],[0,-15],[-64,159]],[[6048,8537],[74,264],[39,361],[44,23],[157,191],[189,-56],[75,-58],[231,-50],[221,137],[80,75],[115,179],[71,306],[113,90],[90,-48],[53,-64],[-61,-119],[134,-9],[249,-56],[172,-125],[132,194],[37,-27],[185,8],[104,-52],[51,-250],[-23,-58],[-68,0],[-251,-146],[-18,-206],[-139,-175],[-56,-23],[8,-146],[-86,-269],[13,-73],[59,-79],[4,-23],[-4,-108],[-47,-29],[-18,-48],[-28,2],[-8,-58],[203,-188],[78,44],[301,31],[73,-225],[-29,-44],[-109,-162],[-71,-19],[-42,-12],[-92,4],[-168,162],[-311,-56],[-28,-48],[59,-66],[65,56],[-32,-102],[-33,-288],[-75,-71],[-3,-8],[-408,329],[-402,279],[-31,-70],[-119,97],[-19,103],[79,164],[-134,-58],[-50,-115],[-61,2],[-148,117],[-78,29],[-125,121],[-76,117],[-123,318],[16,84]],[[2267,4325],[128,29],[258,-90]],[[2653,4264],[-103,-127],[-165,-125],[-432,-525],[-132,-21],[51,-37],[-48,-56],[18,-86],[138,-183]],[[1980,3104],[59,-183],[-88,-44],[-44,-94],[86,-131],[-270,-311],[163,-218],[-33,-169],[-138,-75],[35,-125],[-40,-8]],[[1710,1746],[-81,50],[-262,-188],[-523,588],[-25,68],[-111,55],[-9,81],[61,87],[-75,206],[12,121],[-128,59],[-257,-57],[-65,230],[-123,52],[-86,70],[-38,86],[11,12],[514,669],[70,-48],[134,-164],[14,108],[65,29],[-27,125],[15,73],[94,42],[12,79],[44,-54],[-50,143],[100,-108],[82,-29],[258,-167],[69,38],[172,2],[58,-69],[163,117],[115,12],[313,-54],[119,63],[-78,252]],[[4999,4329],[130,37],[272,-223],[74,32],[-30,-152],[-77,-100],[52,-19],[-27,-134],[94,34],[13,-42],[113,48],[12,-71],[99,-225],[-92,-35],[73,-106],[-27,-109],[69,-21],[312,65],[-50,-167],[64,-48],[-71,-133],[-16,-29]],[[5986,2931],[-13,8],[-63,-10],[-17,-2],[-10,-2],[-10,0],[-34,-2],[-17,-7],[-23,2],[-8,-2],[-99,-95],[88,-200],[-345,-296],[-96,41],[-17,50],[-17,15],[2,29],[-27,71],[-38,27],[-67,8],[-14,-22],[-185,-23],[-31,-17],[-13,60],[122,40],[33,73],[-96,102],[2,75],[111,102],[-287,19],[-54,-54],[-44,27],[-75,64],[-114,159],[-56,-50],[-92,33],[-88,79],[-21,104],[-153,52],[-40,138],[-4,-2],[-63,191],[-81,15],[69,50],[186,292],[191,108],[75,-38],[59,-123],[297,69],[46,94],[75,33],[61,40],[8,73]],[[720,7391],[268,406],[163,-108],[174,104],[180,-6],[281,75],[146,196],[67,29],[147,-29],[335,308],[-50,171],[92,70],[148,-47],[181,-238],[-21,-35],[-116,83],[-44,162],[-83,25],[-30,-31],[-19,-229],[-90,-142],[-111,-77],[3,-98],[-182,-33],[20,-106],[111,-38],[-69,-181],[-104,2],[-55,-91],[-75,-46],[-6,-119],[75,-54],[-84,0],[6,-83],[128,2],[122,-38],[-7,-133],[-73,50],[-17,-59],[128,-79],[90,-6],[-203,-229],[-82,-125],[-94,0],[-102,-90],[18,-64],[-108,-38],[12,-29],[-195,-39],[-75,-175],[-48,-119],[-32,-25],[-121,169],[-109,54],[-8,35],[-57,121],[-40,112],[-46,36],[-10,56],[-23,-4],[-138,250],[-203,354],[35,173]],[[4623,6197],[63,-56],[102,96],[38,-48],[115,48],[52,-52],[126,-190],[-63,-39],[77,14],[99,-166],[-44,-175],[-25,-119],[-400,-23],[50,-119],[-58,-35],[-42,-217],[-423,233],[-53,36],[-123,-148],[-86,-200],[-46,-46],[-33,-19]],[[3949,4972],[-19,-18],[-82,158],[-2,4],[-25,27],[-25,38],[-46,121],[21,29],[-70,62],[122,204],[29,73],[17,61]],[[5385,6139],[115,271],[4,339],[19,75],[-42,9],[94,106],[145,79],[92,17],[-63,-36],[-50,-125],[113,-77],[82,46],[117,-152],[-30,-37],[63,-59],[34,40],[121,-109],[193,-27],[25,209],[35,0],[2,89],[44,-54],[999,27],[103,-85],[-36,-100],[-61,-159],[-131,-345],[-9,-25],[0,-2],[-167,-30],[-134,77],[-94,-10],[-114,-52],[-98,-90],[-111,-18],[-69,-50],[-191,39],[-251,-31],[-46,-185],[27,-46],[-35,-31],[-65,-42],[-50,54],[-53,-148],[-94,29],[6,-110],[-125,264],[-111,169],[-96,188],[-139,39],[32,69]],[[3949,4972],[29,-45],[-50,-180],[56,-97],[50,-15],[-12,-90],[-147,-70],[-117,-109],[-15,-50],[136,-208],[-20,-94],[115,-158],[4,-23],[-145,208],[-88,0],[-62,-46],[-84,42],[61,63],[-239,102],[-73,-257],[-111,-62],[58,-90],[195,-210],[-109,-98],[-107,110],[-75,-14],[-13,60],[-73,-23],[-98,61],[60,250],[155,335],[-54,-75],[-195,-173],[-125,-131],[44,106],[-241,48],[52,63],[159,29],[-109,116],[-6,125],[-102,-108]],[[2267,4325],[-102,41],[-25,15],[153,239],[240,490],[155,235],[142,248],[91,69],[60,-60],[136,54],[143,479],[17,2],[79,-61],[13,34]],[[8967,4979],[295,233],[119,392],[430,518],[188,-62],[-36,-159],[-178,-154],[-52,-43],[-184,-357],[-92,-298],[-136,-29],[-92,-108],[-130,-56],[-124,2],[-8,121]],[[4999,4329],[23,121],[82,64],[-50,67],[31,-2],[67,-17],[139,169],[-28,29],[4,112],[70,-54],[54,98],[142,-129],[-37,-31],[106,-102],[57,21],[-86,58],[90,96],[86,-36],[-56,-283],[121,-83],[130,-125],[60,143],[11,36],[255,-100],[-21,-165],[-62,-60],[12,-206],[207,-82],[74,-123],[58,-152],[-109,-231],[-58,-64],[-52,-111],[-45,-225],[-50,-64],[-81,-48],[-157,81]],[[1980,3104],[91,-136],[77,-239],[142,-156],[128,179],[101,-88],[-44,-64],[4,-196],[176,140],[129,93],[126,-112],[32,208],[98,69],[8,60],[117,52],[15,44],[50,-54],[159,-121],[-77,-183],[27,-25],[59,-48],[-34,-100],[76,-54],[-103,-44],[197,-321],[-67,-50],[-86,-2],[-113,-125],[155,-206],[10,-440],[-716,-520],[30,-73],[119,-159],[-4,-56],[-78,-29],[3,-56],[-76,-96],[-42,-11],[-138,-185],[-21,23],[-477,456],[-71,548],[-95,617],[-157,102]]],"transform":{"scale":[0.000023837383738373528,0.000016953495349535314],"translate":[-71.191155,42.22788]}}
```

Comment: Swapping the topojson for a test one, this script works for me, do you get any errors in the console? Does the console log the expected results? And can you share the topojson (mapshaper will show a topojson even if the projection is not wgs84 for example).

Comment: Just added zips.topojson!

Comment: No, I don't get any errors and it consoles the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your topojson, it is possible that the script is working. The features are very tiny, invisible even  (but visible in the DOM upon inspection) . To view the features, you can change your projection to:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
.scale(100000)
.center([-71,42.3])
```

[image]

Your data is projected in CRS84, which should still be visible when projecting the data, there may be a mistake in the scale factor used in the topojson which seems unusually small `"transform":{"scale":[0.000023837383738373528,0.000016953495349535314]`.

Three solutions come to mind:

1. Find projection parameters that work for your needs (such as the parameters above).
2. Reproject the data into WGS84 (lat long pairs).
3. Use d3.geoTransform to scale and transform your data, which might be tricky.